# Como fazer um TextBox aceitar somente as letras S e N?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou estudando sobre `TextBox` em C# e não tenho ideia de como fazer essa função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No arquivo `.xaml` da sua `Window` coloque o seguinte código. O que importa aqui é o evento `KeyDown="txtTest_KeyDown"`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtTest" KeyDown="txtTest_KeyDown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="239,148,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="282"/>
```

Agora, no `.cs` da sua `Window`, crie o método `txtTest_KeyDown` da seguinte forma:

```
private void txtTest_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key == Key.S || e.Key == Key.N)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, então passa o parâmetro `e` e no if usa o e.Key comparando com um valor??
 Entendi, muito grato Perozzo !! Isso será muito útil

Comment: Na verdade o e.Key é a tecla pressionada dentro do TextBox. Não é necessário passar nada por parâmetro. Criando da forma que lhe mostrei, é tudo feito automático. E sim, é só usar o e.Key e testar com a tecla desejada.

Answer (score 3):

O que ocorre de imediato é interceptar a tecla pressionada, usando o evento `KeyDown`, e verificar qual foi.
Se a tecla corresponde a <kbd>S</kbd> ou <kbd>N</kbd> a implementação deve retornar `e.Handled = false;`, caso contrário retornar `e.Handled = true;`.

Infelizmente isso não é suficiente, desde logo porque a tecla <kbd>space</kbd> não é interceptada.
Por outro lado há a possibilidade de o texto poder ser introduzido via *paste*.

Assim, para lidar com todas as possibilidades, deve tratar os seguintes eventos:

- PreviewTextInput
- PreviewKeyDown
- Paste

e restringir o número de caracteres aceites a 1.

A "melhor" forma para a implementação é escrever um TextBox personalizado que poderá utilizar em qualquer lugar.

```
public class S_N_TextBox : TextBox
{

    public S_N_TextBox()
    {
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(this, PastingHandler);
        MaxLength = 1;
    }

    private void PastingHandler(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var pasteText = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
        //Garante que o texto inserido via paste é válido
        if (!IsValid(pasteText))
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsValid(e.Text))
        {
            //A documentação recomenda que o método base seja chamado.
            base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
            return;
        }
        e.Handled = true;

    }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Não permite o uso do espaço
        e.Handled = e.Key == Key.Space;
    }

    //Determina que texto pode ser aceite
    protected virtual bool IsValid(string input) => input == "S" || input == "N";
}
```

Esta classe pode ser usada como base para outras restrições que queira que um TextBlox tenha. Apenas terá de alterar o método `IsValid`().